# How to get host name from multiple ip address ? Java

Tags: java, networking

I am learning Socket Programming now and I have encountered some problem when want to get host names from multiple ip address, I have succeed getting one but I need to get from several ip address, for example 2.
This is my code:

```
package sample.weblog;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class SampleWeblog {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String ip = null;
    String theRest = null;
    String entry = null;
    int index = 0;

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("f:/file1.txt");
        Reader in = new InputStreamReader(fin);
        BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(in);

        for (entry = bin.readLine();entry != null;entry=bin.readLine()){
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(entry);
        System.out.println(address.getHostName() + " = " + entry);
        }
}
}
```

I enter some ip address into the txt file, for example 8.8.8.8 and 208.65.153.238 which is Google and YouTube. But then the result I get is like this:

[image: output]

Why the second ip address did not get the host name? 
Thank you.

Comment: Use Scanner class instead of buffered reader.

Comment: @GovindMadhu Hey I got my problem, apparently its my ip address not right, I change to yahoo and it's worked. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: @GovindMadhu Why? State your reason. And what does it have to do with the question? For merely reading lines, `BufferedReader.readLine()` is sufficient, probably preferable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The getHostName does a reverse name lookup.  To do this, it must query a service on the internet (DNS) to get the name, if it exists.  In some cases the lookup will fail because the reverse lookup was never configured by the owner of the address, in other cases there will not exist a host name for a given address.

For more details you can read up on DNS reverse name lookup.